# UILabel's text with diagonal strikethrough line

Tags: label, uilabel, strikethrough

I would like to make an effect like this, with UILabel text

[image]

how can I do that? I didn't find any help on web; I just found help with horizontal line

PS: sorry for my bad english, I'm italian :)

Answer (score 6):

enoktate's answer updated to **Swift 4.2**, and written as an extension

```
extension UILabel {
    /// Strikes through diagonally
    /// - Parameters:
    /// - offsetPercent: Improve visual appearance or flip line completely by passing a value between 0 and 1
    func diagonalStrikeThrough(offsetPercent: CGFloat = 0.1) {
        let linePath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height * (1 - offsetPercent)))
        linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height * offsetPercent))

        let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 2
        lineLayer.strokeColor = textColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: If this isn't working for anyone be sure to call `myLabel.sizeToFit()` before calling `myLabel. diagonalStrikeThrough()`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is too late to answer you but this can be helpful for future googlers.
A diagonal strikethrough line can be achieved with adding a CAShapeLayer to your label as a sublayer like I did below:

```
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(0, yourLabel.bounds.height))
    linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(yourLabel.bounds.width, 0))

    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.path = linePath.CGPath
    lineLayer.lineWidth = 2
    lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    yourLabel.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
```