# UILabel text struck through angle

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel, strikethrough

I want to create a UILabel in which the text is like this(like angle not horizontally). Can anyone suggest, please?

[image]

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585420/uilabels-text-with-diagonal-strikethrough-line

Comment: Do you want the text at an angle? Or you want a line striking the horizontal text at an angle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel's text with diagonal strikethrough line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585420/uilabels-text-with-diagonal-strikethrough-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just trim the label width to content size.

```
testLabel.text = "Tk 1,750"
testLabel.frame.size.width = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
```

and then use as told by @fzh

```
testLabel.addSlantLine(slantLineColor: UIColor.lightGray,
                   slantLineWidth: 2,
                   startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: testLabel.frame.height - 2),
                   endPoint: CGPoint(x: testLabel.frame.width, y: 2))
```

**Note**:
 Trim after text update

Answer (score 3):

you can add extension like this:

```
extension UILabel {
    func addSlantLine(slantLineColor: UIColor, slantLineWidth:CGFloat, startPoint: CGPoint, endPoint: CGPoint) {
        let slantLinePath = UIBezierPath()
        slantLinePath.move(to: startPoint)
        slantLinePath.addLine(to: endPoint)

        let slantLineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        slantLineLayer.path = slantLinePath.cgPath
        slantLineLayer.lineWidth = slantLineWidth
        slantLineLayer.strokeColor = slantLineColor.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(slantLineLayer)
    }
}
```

use:

```
testLabel.addSlantLine(slantLineColor: UIColor.lightGray,
                       slantLineWidth: 2,
                       startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: testLabel.frame.height - 2),
                       endPoint: CGPoint(x: testLabel.frame.width, y: 2))
```

Comment: can I set only the strike over the text? because your code is working properly but it is all over the UILabel/

Comment: sorry, i don't know how to implement that only strike the specific text

Comment: testLabel.frame.size.width = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width

from bose answer. Highly appreciate your answer.